# forcenetwork in networkD3 Produces No Graph and No Errors

Tags: r, networkd3

I am trying to produce a simple forcenetwork graph using networkD3 in R, but I do not get any output or errors using the code below.  I have confirmed my node ID's are 0 indexed, numeric values and the name/group fields are characters.  Any help is appreciated.

```
# Load Packages

library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

zz <- "name id  group   source  target  value
A   0   A   0   1   2199
B   1   A   1   0   784
C   2   B   2   4   394
D   3   B   3   2   382
E   4   B   4   8   340
F   5   B   5   9   286
G   6   B   6   5   279
H   7   A   0   7   279
I   8   B   7   0   240
J   9   B   8   0   196
K   10  A   9   0   174"

df<- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)

nodes <- df %>%
  select(name,id,group) %>%
  mutate(name = as.character(name),id = as.numeric(id), group=as.character(group))

links <- df %>%
  select(source,target,value) %>%
  mutate(source = as.numeric(source),target=as.numeric(target),value=as.numeric(value))


# simple with default colours
forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "value",
             Nodesize = 1,
             width = "1000px", 
             height = "600px",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE)

sapply(nodes,class)
sapply(links, class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "value",
           #  Nodesize = 1,
             width = "1000px", 
             height = "600px",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE)
```

As you can see from `?forceNetwork`:

> Nodesize   character string specifying the a column in the Nodes data
>   frame with some value to vary the node radius's with. See also
>   radiusCalculation.

So you are saying that you want column 1 to be the size of your nodes but it requires a string to reference the column and even if a position were accepted, in nodes `data.frame` column 1 are not sizes but names.

So if you want to determine a `Nodesize` create a new column in nodes and assign your desired value. Then, pass the name of that column to `Nodesize`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

zz <- "name id  group   source  target  value
A   0   A   0   1   2199
B   1   A   1   0   784
C   2   B   2   4   394
D   3   B   3   2   382
E   4   B   4   8   340
F   5   B   5   9   286
G   6   B   6   5   279
H   7   A   0   7   279
I   8   B   7   0   240
J   9   B   8   0   196
K   10  A   9   0   174"

df<- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)

nodes <- df %>%
  select(name,id,group) %>%
  mutate(name = as.character(name),id = as.numeric(id), group=as.character(group))

links <- df %>%
  select(source,target,value) %>%
  mutate(source = as.numeric(source),target=as.numeric(target),value=as.numeric(value))

nodes<-nodes %>% mutate(size=100)


forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "value",
            Nodesize = "size",
             width = "1000px", 
             height = "600px",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE)
```